# Como criar uma trigger para uma Procedure executar todos os dias em determinado horário?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho a seguinte procedure:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `consolida_consumo`()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO consolidacao_consumo
    (   quantidade_chamada,
        id_usuario,
        id_funcao_api,
        data_created,
        data_updated,
        quantidade_retorno,
        quantidade_kbytes)
    SELECT
        count(*),
        id_usuario,
        id_funcao_api,
        data_hora,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS data_updated,
        SUM(qnt_retorno),
        SUM(qnt_bytes)
    FROM
        teste.log_acesso
    WHERE
        data_hora BETWEEN ADDDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    GROUP BY
        id_usuario,
        id_funcao_api;
        
    DELETE FROM teste.log_acesso WHERE data_hora BETWEEN ADDDATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
END
```

E gostaria que ela fosse executada todos os dias por exemplo às 00:00.
Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender como fazer isso?

Comment: *"gostaria que ela fosse executada todos os dias..."* deve configurar isso no banco de dados https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html

Answer (score -2):

Para criar uma trigger que execute uma procedure todos os dias em um determinado horário, você pode usar a instrução CREATE EVENT. A sintaxe básica é a seguinte:

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY interval
    STARTS start_time
    ENDS end_time
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
DO
    BEGIN
        -- instruções da procedure aqui
    END;
```

No lugar de "event_name", você deve colocar o nome da trigger. No lugar de "interval", você deve especificar o intervalo de tempo em que a trigger deve ser executada. Por exemplo, para executar a trigger todos os dias, você pode usar "INTERVAL 1 DAY". No lugar de "start_time" e "end_time", você deve especificar o horário de início e de término da trigger. Por exemplo, para executar a trigger todos os dias às 00:00, você pode usar "STARTS '00:00:00' ENDS '24:00:00'".

A seguir está um exemplo de como criar uma trigger para executar a procedure "consolida_consumo" todos os dias às 00:00:

```
CREATE EVENT consolida_consumo_daily
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '00:00:00'
    ENDS '24:00:00'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
DO
    BEGIN
        CALL consolida_consumo();
    END;
```

Observe que a instrução "ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE" indica que a trigger será excluída quando for completada. Se você deseja que a trigger continue sendo executada periodicamente, pode remover essa instrução.

Comment: A declaração [`CREATE EVENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) não cria triggers cria **EVENTOS**. Triggers(gatilhos) são criados com a declaração [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html).